# how to write Firestore security rules to also allow null value and undefined value in a single field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a field in my Firestore document called `lastApproval` that should be a timestamp if it has a value.

this is my simplified rules

```
match /users/{userID} {

  allow create: if isValidUserStructure(incomingData())
  allow update: if isValidUserStructure(incomingData())

}

function incomingData() {
  return request.resource.data;
}


function isValidUserStructure(user) {
    return  user.email is string
         && user.fullname is string
         && user.lastApproval is timestamp  // error in here

}
```

as you can see, `isValidUserStructure` function will be used to check when creating and updating user document.

when creating user document, that `lastApproval` field will be null like this

```
const data = {
  fullname: 'John Doe',
  email: 'my@email.com',
  lastApproval: null
};

await db.collection('users').doc('userIDHere').set(data);
```

but when updating document, I only want timestamp.

```
const data = {
  lastApproval: new Date()
};

await db.collection('users').doc('userIDHere').update(data);
```

and also, I want to pass the security rules if `lastApproval` is not available, for example, if the user only want to update the fullname like this

```
const data = {
  fullname: "My New Name"
};

await db.collection('users').doc('userIDHere').update(data);
```

so I want my security rules to accept timestamp, null and undefined value for `lastApproval` field

I have tried but error

[image]

please help :)

Comment: One important bit if other people had the same issue I had : you need to send the field key that you wanna check against (in example up is `lastApproval = null` ) otherwise the rule won't work. Firestore rules do not support `user.lastApproval == undefined` .
Make sure to include the field key even if it's null, otherwise the rule won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any type `null` as far as I know. You can find all available types in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/).

If you want to check if the value is null then try `user.lastApproval == null` instead. To check if the `lastApproval`  property exists at first place, try this:

```js
match /collection/{doc} {
  allow write: if 'lastApproval' in request.resource.data && (..otherLogic)
}
```

So you can write your function as:

```js
function isValidUserStructure(user) {
    return  user.email is string
         && user.fullname is string
         && (('lastApproval' in user && user.lastApproval is timestamp) || !('lastApproval' in user)) 
}
```

Comment: @Alexa289 you should check if that field it defined at first place. `(('lastApproval' in user && user.lastApproval is timestamp) || !('lastApproval' in user))`. Here `!(lastApproval in user)` means that field is missing but you still want to allow write as email and name field are valid.

Comment: Are firestore `&&` and `||` operators lazy? If so, couldn't `(('lastApproval' in user && user.lastApproval is timestamp) || !('lastApproval' in user))` be shortened to `(!('lastApproval' in user) || user.lastApproval is timestamp)` ?